# Jenkins build step is unable to delete directory

Tags: maven, jenkins

Until recently everything worked fine with our build process in Jenkins. We got a quite big project with many modules and a complicated dependency structure.
Suddenly, the build fails with error messages like the following:

> Failed to execute goal *certain-plugin*:109:*certainEar*(*certainEar*)
>   on project app: *certain plugin*: Can't explode ear file
>   'app-SNAPSHOT.ear': Error, directory can't be deleted

The maven command that gets executed in the build pipeline and results in the error message is the following:

`mvn -B -U package -DskipTests`

A temporary workaround is manually deleting the affected directory. Previously I had a similar problem with the deletion of an ear, there it was possible to exclude the affected ear from this build step as it was not required there. Afterwards I got the error message mentioned above.

Now I found a (kind of) final solution: Adding *clean* to the targets of the maven command:

`mvn -B -U clean package -DskipTests`

Now the building step works fine. But why the heck does this happen? Do you have any hints what could lead to this behavior? I'm quite clueless to say the least.

Somehow this could have something to do with the extraction of an ear out of our big app ear. Shortly after we finished this and merged it into our master branch those errors began to arise. As I was not involved in this work it's hard to track down what happened there exactly and what could lead to this behavior. In parallel I will investigate what the colleagues did there. Hints from you what the reasons could be will certainly help to track this down.

I found nothing similar to this error messages online that helped me in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution "mvn clean" indicates me that your job is executing on a jenkins workspace that contains the execution of the previous job. I would recommend to always start your job by clearing what's in the workspace. In freestyle job, under section Source Code Management you can add the behavior

Wipe out repository & force clone

in pipelines, you would use checkout step

```
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace']] + [[$class: 'PruneStaleBranch']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[
                    url: '<git_url>'
                ]]
            ])
```

there are other ways to clean a workspace in a pipeline like cleanWS and deleteDir. Do prefer the checkout WipeWorkspace plugin